# Can an unbounded sequence have a convergent cesaro mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cesaro-summable

I was wondering if an unbounded sequence may have a convergent cesaro mean ($\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$). I was maybe thinking of $$a_n = (-n)^n$$
as a sequence having a convergent mean, but I might be wrong. Anyways, how would you proceed to prove such an intuition?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't think this example works, the Cesaro means of this sequence have $\pm 1/2$ as accumulation points.

Comment: @Wojowu: oh, you're right. Well, minor fix: $a_n=(-1)^n \sqrt{n}$ works (actually, $a_n=(-1)^n n^{1-\varepsilon}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ works as well).

Comment: Oops, don't mind me missing the unbounded requirement.

Comment: In general, $a_n$ must be alternating in some sense for convergence to be possible.

Comment: Let's try $a_n = (-n)^n.$ If $n$ is even, then

$$a_1 + \cdots + a_n >n^n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^k > n^n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-1)^{n-1} = n^n - (n-1)\cdot (n-1)^{n-1} = n^n(1 - [(n-1)/n]^n).$$

Now $[(n-1)/n]^n \to 1/e.$ Thus for large $n$ we have

$$a_1 + \cdots + a_n > n^n(1 - 1/2).$$

Dividing that by $n$ gives rapid divergence to $\infty.$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example where all $a_n$ are nonnegative. If $n = 2^m, m = 1,2, \dots ,$ define $a_n = m.$ For all other $n$ define $a_n =0.$  Then $(a_n)$ is unbounded. But if $2^m\le n < 2^{m+1},$ then

$$\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \le \frac{1 + 2 + \cdots + m}{2^m} = \frac{m(m+1)/2}{2^m}.$$

The fraction on the right $\to 0$ as $m\to \infty,$ showing the Cesaro means $\to 0.$

Comment: I think this answer deserves to be chosen as the best  answer over mine!

Comment: @AlexQ: Why not chose this answer as the correct one?

Comment: Clear and precise

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example following the same basic idea that zhw gave, but with non-zero limit:

For a given $n$, determine the highest power of $2$ that divides $n$,  say $2^m$. Define $a_n:=m$. So we are talking about the sequence:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&...\\
\hline
a_n&0&1&0&2&0&1&0&3&0&1&0&2&0&1&0&4&...\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The idea is that $1/2$ of the sequence is at least $1$, $1/4$ is at least $2$, $1/8$ is at least $3$ etc. so on average we have $1/2+1/4+1/8+...=1$ as the Cesaro mean in the limit, as I will show in detail below.

---

Then it turns out that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}\lfloor n/2^m\rfloor
\approx n
$$
Each term in the last sum will differ less than $1$ from the content of the floor function
$$
\lfloor n/2^m\rfloor\in(n/2^m-1,n/2^m]
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}\lfloor n/2^m\rfloor
>\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} (n/2^m-1)
=\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} n/2^m-\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor
$$
and since
$$
\sum_{m=1}^t n/2^m=n-\frac{n}{2^t}
$$
we have
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} n/2^m-\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor=n-\frac{n}{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}}-\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor
$$
On the other hand $\sum_{m=1}^\infty n/2^m=n$ is an upper bound on this sum from which it follows that
$$
n-\frac{n}{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}}-\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor\leq\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\leq n
$$
Hence it should be evident that $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\to 1$. Finally, note that $a_{2^m}=m$ so $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded.

---

Multiplying the sequence from above by any $c\in\mathbb R$ we can construct a non-bounded sequence with Cesaro means converging to that $c$.

Comment: you could also let $a_n$ be what I had, and set  $b_n=1$ for all $n.$ Then  $c_n = a_n+b_n$ is unbounded and the C-means of $c_n$ tend to $1.$

Comment: @zhw: Yes, you are absolutely right of course :o) My aim was to make the non-zero elements "denser" to see how that could lead to non-zero limits. Your solution is very nice BTW!

Answer (score 0):

Take the following example

$u_{2n}=-\sqrt{n}$

and

$u_{2n+1}=\sqrt{n}$

then

$v_{2n}=0$

and

$v_{2n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n+1}$.

$(u_n)$ is unbounded.

$(v_n)$ goes to $0$.

Comment: That is far more intuitive than my sequence, how would you prove that (vn) converges to 0 (which seems logical)?

Comment: the two susequences $v_{2n}$ and $v_{2n+1}$ tend to $0$, so ...